# Securing only REST controller with Spring Security custom token stateless while keeping regular state full web login working

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-security, jwt

I have looked into the OAuth examples and it looks like an overkill for my scenario. I have a web application working with Spring security having users and authorities stored in database. I want to secure only partial "/rest/**" controllers with stateless token. JWT looks like a nice way to do it but I couldn't find an example filtering only some path "/rest/**" and securing it with stateless token while keeping the rest of the paths secured with state full session or not secured at all. Please post some example on how to establish the forking request between the paths "/rest/**" or not and using stateless token security ( JWT or any other custom token) for "/rest/**" and state full security for the others "/others/**" ?

Comment: Do you use xml-based or Java-based configuration?

Comment: No, it's spring boot application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is an example of how to secure your UI controllers with form login and your REST controllers with http basic auth. The example runs with Spring Boot and is reduced to the configuration required to secure different endpoints in different ways.

I have no example demonstrating how to replace the http basic auth but you might find [this blog post](http://technicalrex.com/2015/02/20/stateless-authentication-with-spring-security-and-jwt) helpful.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{


    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public static class RestApiWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Bean
        CorsFilter corsFilter() {
            CorsFilter filter = new CorsFilter();
            return filter;
        }

        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
            .addFilterBefore(corsFilter(), SessionManagementFilter.class)
            .csrf().disable()
            .antMatcher("/rest-api/v1/**").authorizeRequests().anyRequest().hasAnyRole("APIClient")
            .and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .httpBasic();
        }
    }


    @Configuration
    @Order(2)
    public static class UILoginWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
        @Bean
        CorsFilter corsFilter() {
            CorsFilter filter = new CorsFilter();
            return filter;
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
            .addFilterBefore(corsFilter(), SessionManagementFilter.class)
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/other/**").access("hasRole('whatever goes here')")
            // ...
            .and()
            .formLogin().loginPage("/login")
            //...
            .sessionManagement().sessionFixation().newSession().maximumSessions(1)
            .sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry());
        }    
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! this works nicely for having separate security settings for web login and stateless rest calls, as you pointed out can be extended with JWT or Oauth, but I think it's solves my main issue.